# How can I write into a file adding to a new line every time?

Tags: node.js, json, file, append, discord.js

Lets say I have a script that logs a random input to the console such as

```
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

console.log(makeid(5));
```

every time its run it will log something like:

```
//ran once v
2nJr6
//ran again v
w9II3
//and again v
3j9Je
```

How can I make these append to a file such as:

File name: Random.txt
File Content:

```
2nJr6
w9II3
3j9Je
```

USING NODEJS

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback

Comment: @tkausl if i make it append \n will it go to the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');

function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

console.log(makeid(5));

fs.appendFile('Random.txt', makeid(5) + '\n', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```